# How do I capture the sub-string of numeric characters at the end of the string?

Tags: regex

```
Confirmation number
236GE46326Z21C05
Invoice details
From
Consolidated Text ABCD 1111
To
Test Test Test 2222
Frequency
```

The above is the text that I am looking through to extract numeric characters.

I used the following Regex to detect the string of characters below "From".

```
(?<=From\r\n).+
```

I need to extract the "1111" out of the string.

Comment: `From\R.*?(\d+)` captures the first number after `From` in capture group 1. Assuming "dot all" is not set it cannot match further than 1 line. So if the line below `From` does not include a number, no match will be found. `\R` is a shorthand for `\r?\n` in most regex dialects.

Comment: Hi Wiktor - thank you - this worked with a small modification.  I used the following (?<=From\r\n.*?(\d{4})) to capture all 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try out https://regex101.com/ to try and understand how your regex works.

For this particular example that you have put in. you can use the regex

`From.*\n[^\d]*(?<required_number>\d*)\n`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern.

```
(?s)From.+?(\d+)$
```

The `(?s)`, will toggle-on *single-line* mode, causing a *dot*, ., to additionally match new-line delimiters.
The `?` will assure the `.+` matches up to the first `\d` occurrence.
And, the `$` will assure it is the last sequence of `\d` in the line.

Output, for group 1.

```
1111
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match `From` followed by a newline.

Then match the whole next line, and either match the preceding whitespace char without a newline before the digits with `[^\S\r\n]`, or use a word boundary `\b` to prevent a partial word match.

To get the digits, use a capture group.

```
\bFrom\r?\n.*\b(\d+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NUV300/1)

Or

```
\bFrom\r?\n.*[^\S\r\n](\d+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OEBmUv/1)

**Note** that if `From` is at the start of the string, then you can append an anchor `^From\r?\n`